# Based on which criteria google AJAX Search API will give search results?

Tags: api, search

I have used google search API to get the results of google search but it gives me different results as I have searched directly in google.com.

So,if anyone know here how is it possible then let me know.why both results are not same for same search keyword ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the filter option for duplicate content and perhaps language option cause the results to differ.